# Add an "add item" to a spinner in android. Possible?

Tags: android, spinner, android-cursoradapter

I'm using a custom `CursorAdapter` for my spinner. Now I want to add a item called "*add new item*", to add new items to my spinner. Is such a function possible and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used to add a custom element to a spinner was this:

```
        cursor=<MyOriginalCursor>

        MatrixCursor prompt = new MatrixCursor(PROJECTION, 1);
        prompt.addRow(new Object[]{_ID_ALL, "All"});

        MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{prompt, cursor});
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(mergeCursor);
```

The MergeCursor joins two Cursors together, handling all the nitty gritty with next element, number of elements etc. The MatrixCursor can be used to create a cursor that is backed by an array. In the onItemSelected method I can now check for the special ID supplied here and do special logic for "All" or "Nothing", whatever the case may be.